# Identifying the last time a value was used in a column based upon dates in another column

Tags: sql

I'm presently looking at a data set that records each time a note is placed on a client's record. Each note can be given a specific type, and I'm trying to identify how to identify the last time each note type was used.

The table is like the one below:

| PERSON_ID | NOTE_TYPE | DATE_CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | NOTE1 | 02/01/2022 |
| 121654 | NOTE12 | 03/04/2015 |
| 115135 | NOTE1 | 25/06/2020 |

The Person ID is irrelevant - what I need is data like the one below, only showing each note type once, and the date it was last used:

| NOTE_TYPE | DATE_CREATED |
| --- | --- |
| NOTE1 | 02/01/2022 |
| NOTE12 | 03/04/2015 |

I'm relatively new to SQL and have tried some very basic code, including adapting an example I found online:

```
SELECT NOTE_TYPE, 
       DATE_CREATED
from ( SELECT NOTE_TYPE, 
              DATE_CREATED, 
              ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by NOTE_TYPE order by DATE_CREATED) as rn
      from CASE_NOTES
) t
where rn = 1
ORDER BY DATE_CREATED
```

I know this doesn't work because one note type that was used yesterday came back with it having last been used in 2004!

Comment: *note type that was used yesterday came back with it having last been used in 2004* how is this possible? IF it was last used yesterday then, yesterday is last time used. On your query you are only missing `DESC` after `order by DATE_CREATED` in the row number function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a simple aggregation:

```
Select Note_Type, max(Date_Created) Date_Created
from t
group by Note_Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   NOTE_TYPE, 
   DATE_CREATED
from
(
   SELECT
      NOTE_TYPE, 
      DATE_CREATED, 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by NOTE_TYPE order by DATE_CREATED DESC) as rn
   from CASE_NOTES
) t
where rn = 1
ORDER BY DATE_CREATED
```